# JavaScript Update multiple object properties

Tags: javascript

I have this code below that finds the index of specific object using findIndex method and Update object's name property. Is there anyway i can update mutiple object's name property? E.g.

```
var rofl = ["0"];
```

// Instead of ["0"] how do i update multiple object by putting var rofl = ["1","2","3"];

```
let myArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "Jhon"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
],

objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.id == rofl));

console.log("Before update: ", myArray[objIndex]) // {id: 0, name: "Jhon"}

myArray[objIndex].name = ("Jerry");

console.log("After update: ", myArray[objIndex]) // {id: 0, name: "Jerry"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let myArray = [{id: 0, name: "Jhon"},{id: 1, name: "Sara"},{id: 2, name: "Domnic"},{id: 3, name: "Bravo"}];
let rofl = ["1","2","3"];

myArray.forEach((obj) => {if(rofl.includes(obj.id.toString())) obj.name = 'Jerry'}) 

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `forEach` instead:

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "Jhon"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
];
["1","2","3"].forEach(findId =>
  myArray.find(({ id }) => id == findId).name = 'Jerry'
);
console.log(myArray);
```

If the IDs have a chance of not existing in the array, you'll have to add a test for that as well:

```js
const myArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "Jhon"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
];
["1","2","3", "10"].forEach(findId => {
  const foundObj = myArray.find(({ id }) => id == findId);
  if (foundObj) foundObj.name = 'Jerry';
});
console.log(myArray);
```